# php to make url shortener

Tags: php, url-shortener

i have made a url shortener you can check here [Puny URL shortener](http://puny.gq)

It make a url something like www.puny.gq/?l=xx
Any suggetion to make it something like
www.puny.gq/xx

Answer (score 2):

It is called [URL rewriting](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

It depends on the the web server you are using.

For nginx server you can do it like this :

```
server {        
    rewrite ^(/.*)$ /?l=$1 last;
```

For apache see this : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SEO-freindly links. They will do something like this.
You have to modify your `.htaccess` for apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/to
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?l=$1
```

This is a very basic example. You have to adjust it, but it will rewrite the `/xx` to `/index.php?l=xx`

Comment: @AliveColdJuan I don't know about your server structure. It might be necessary to add the RewriteBase to your .htaccess

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: No , i removed .htaccess that i created

Comment: If your index.php is in /abc/public then try RewriteBase /abc/public

Comment: Did you pasted it between RewriteEngine On and the RewriteRule? have a look at the updated answer

Comment: Ok but I think this is what you are searching. Just test a bit :)